# Target all <label> tags and store in a associative array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to get all the label tag in a document and store their text values as the key in an associative array and the value of for="" attribute as its value.

Example: Suppose i have

```
<label for="name">First Name</label>
```

The array should store for all the fields in a form

```
var arr['First Name'] = 'name';
```

I thought about counting the number of Labels and using a for loop to build this array

```
<script>
     function getLabels(){
       var labels = document.getElementsByTagName("label");

      for (var i=0; i<labels.length;i++){
          var arr[labels.textContent] = labels.htmlFor;
      }
     return arr;
     }
</script>
```

The following is a sample html document

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Form Test</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="form.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="/my-handling-form-page" method="post">
    <div>
        <label for="unknow">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="unknow" name="user_name">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="unknow2">E-mail:</label>
        <input type="email" id="unknow2" name="user_mail">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="unknow3">Message:</label>
        <textarea id="unknow3" name="user_message"></textarea>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: An associative array in JavaScript is called an Object. Arrays themselves can only associate items in the array with indexes.

Comment: How can i work around that ? I need to be able to use the Labels text to get the field ID

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: `var arr[labels.textContent] = labels.htmlFor;` is invalid JavaScript. I recommend to read a JavaScript tutorial: http://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An associative array in JavaScript is called an Object. Arrays themselves can only associate items in the array with indexes which are always non-negative integers.

So, gather up all the labels in a JavaScript array, loop over them and, as you do, add properties (keys) to a new object and set the value of the key to the values from the label attribute.

```js
function getLabels(){

  // Get all the label elements and place them in a JavaScript array
  var labels = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("label"));

  // Create an object that will hold the keys and values we need
  var obj = {};

  // Loop over the label array
  labels.forEach(function(lbl){
    // Create a key in the object with the name of the label's content
    // and a value for the key that is the value of the "for" attribute
    obj[lbl.textContent] = lbl.htmlFor;
  });
  
  // Return the now populated object
  return obj;
}

// Print the object for testing:
console.log(getLabels());
```

```html
<form action="/my-handling-form-page" method="post">
    <div>
        <label for="unknow">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="unknow" name="user_name">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="unknow2">E-mail:</label>
        <input type="email" id="unknow2" name="user_mail">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="unknow3">Message:</label>
        <textarea id="unknow3" name="user_message"></textarea>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track. To mimic an associative array in JS you can use an object. Also, declare the object variable *outside* your loop, otherwise you'll just make a new object every iteration.

**Edit:** As a commenter pointed out, it would be better to use `.querySelectorAll()` over `.getElementsByTagName()` in this case. The latter returns a live NodeList, which isn't performant to iterate over.

Something like this:

```js
function getLabels() {
  var labels = document.querySelectorAll('label');
  var store = {};
  
  for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
    var label = labels[i];
    store[label.getAttribute('for')] = label.textContent;
  }
  
  return store;
}
```

Comment: `.getElementsByTagName()` returns a live node list and there are limited use cases for that.

Comment: @ScottMarcus True, but I don't see a reason not to use it here.

Comment: Because every time you iterate over the loop, the entire DOM will be scanned for all label elements **twice** which is extremely wasteful.

Comment: You mean every time you call `getLabels`? I don't think the OP needs to worry about optimization at this point.

Comment: No, I mean upon each iteration of the loop. Let's say there are 10 labels and you call `getLabels()`. Every time you iterate the loop (10 times), you will scan the DOM for all `label` elements 2 times (once when `labels.length` is checked and again when `labels[i]` is accessed). So, after calling `getLabels()` just once, you will have scanned the DOM looking for `label` elements 20 times instead of just once, which is all that is needed here.

Comment: Wow, did not know about static vs. live nodelists. I'll update my answer.

Comment: That's a big reason why `.querySelectorAll()` was created. FYI: you also get a live node list with `.getElementsByClassName()` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here I'm getting all `label` elements, then create an empty object. Then I iterate through all this elements and add new property to `obj`, using inner text of each item, and give it a value equal to `for` attribute value.

```js
var items = document.querySelectorAll('label');
var obj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  obj[items[i].innerText] = items[i].getAttribute('for');
}
console.log(obj)
```

```html
<label for="name1">First Name</label>
<label for="name2">Second Name</label>
<label for="name3">Third Name</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you're trying to reinitialize the variable `arr` every time through the loop. Instead you'll want to initialize an object outside of the loop.

```
<script>
     function getLabels(){
      var labels = document.getElementsByTagName("label");
      var obj = {};
      for (var i=0; i<labels.length;i++){
          var obj[labels.textContent] = labels.htmlFor;
      }
     return obj;
     }
</script>
```

Also, here is an ES6 answer:

```
<script>
  const getLabels = () => {
    const labels = {};
    document.querySelectorAll('label').forEach(e => labels[e.innerText] = e.htmlFor);
    return labels;
  }
</script>
```